# The distinction between graphene supercapacitors and reduced graphite oxide supercapacitors

Tags: synthesis, home-experiment

Looking at [this study, Direct laser writing of micro-supercapacitors on hydrated graphite oxide films](http://www.nature.com/nnano/journal/v6/n8/abs/nnano.2011.110.html), a consumer laser cutter is used to synthesize reduced graphite oxide supercapacitors from hydrated graphite oxide film.

In a similar [study at UCLA (scalable fabrication of high-power graphene micro-supercapacitors)](http://www.nature.com/ncomms/journal/v4/n2/full/ncomms2446.html), graphite oxide film is used again but "LightScribed" by a LightScribe DVD player to form graphene supercapacitors.

**What is the distinction between reduced graphite oxide and graphene. And why are the products of laser treated graphite oxide different in these papers?**